# ftp connection closed before server asking for password

Tags: ftp, client

When trying to connect from machine1 (SUSE Linux) to `example.com` ftp server, I get the following message before the password input prompt. It never verified the password:

```
cata@machine1:~> ftp example.com
Connected to example.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Name (example.com:cata): username@example.com
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection.
```

As you can see, it doesn't even verify the password.

---

But when I connect from machine2 (Ubuntu Linux), it works:

```
catalinubuntu@machine2:~> ftp example.com
Connected to example.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
Name (example.com:catalinubuntu): username@example.com
331 User username@example.com OK. Password required
Password:
```

As you can see, in this case, password prompt appears and I'm able to login.
Is there any FTP client settings that I can adjust?

Comment: The two machines are on the same lan?

Comment: No. Different LANs. But I don't think this can be related to network address. Interesting thing is, if I try to connect from the first machine with a generated short username string, like u@example.com, it prompts me with the password input. It's like the username string length is limited on my client machine1.